# Why alt text its added deafault on my product image DAWN theme

Tags: shopify, product

Im customizing Media gallery of Product page in Shopify DAWN theme, and here i added if condition to not show images that doesnt have same ALT text with the selected variant.

However on this case i need that images that dont have ALT text dont include on this condition.

But images without ALT text are included anyway because i see now that these images are getting as ALT text the name of product.

In short description: My images that doesnt have ALT text ( are empty ) are getting Alt text the name of product.

```
<li
            {% if product.selected_or_first_available_variant.featured_image.alt != media.alt and product.selected_or_first_available_variant.featured_image.alt != blank and media.alt != product.title %}
                  style="display:none!important"
              {% endif %}
              thumbnail-alt="{{ media.alt }}"
              id="Slide-Thumbnails-{{ section.id }}-{{ forloop.index }}{{ id_append }}"
              class="thumbnail-list__item slider__slide{% if section.settings.hide_variants and variant_images contains media.src %} thumbnail-list_item--variant{% endif %}"
              data-target="{{ section.id }}-{{ media.id }}"
              data-media-position="{{ media_index }}"
            >
</li>
```